# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Q

Tags: calculus

The FTC is often written as:

If $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ then $F'(x) = f(x)$.

Is it not also true that:

If $F(x) = \int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ then $F'(x) = f(x)$?

What is the difference? Is it just the same thing written in a different way?

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing

Comment: @Oliver What does the symbol $\int f(x)\,\text{d}x$ mean to you?

Comment: By the way, what is calculus Q? Is it quantum calculus?

Comment: No, Q stood for Question. The symbol means indefinite integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second case is a *definition* of the anti-derivative.

The first one is a relationship between geometric interpretation (typically area under the curve $f$) to the anti-derivative defined in the second case. This relationship is known as the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ is defined by your first definite integral, then we understand it as a function of a variable $x$.

If you define $F$ as an indefinite integral, i.e., $F$ is an indefinite integral, it is de facto a class of all functions that have a common derivative.

So formally the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus applies to the first case.

The case of indefinite integral is "true" in the sense of an abuse of language.